# Should one say Hashem's name when reading a pasuk in Aramaic?

Tags: targumin

When doing a pasuk for shnayim mikrah, one may say Hashem's name if he completes the pasuk. However, when reading Onkeles, is one allowed to say Hashem's name? Meaning, does saying a full pasuk in Onkeles get the same treatment as saying a full pasuk when reading the Torah?

Comment: What does "full pasuk" have to do with saying God's name?

Comment: are you making an assumption that, one may say Hashem's name ONLY if he completes the pasuk. maybe prove that. then your question will be so solid.

Comment: Beginning of Gemara Brachos the Chacham Tzvi (Father of r emden) has tshuvah that it's mutar to do so regardless of Kavana. Although there are those that are machmir. One has to know himself.

Answer (score 1):

yes. In fact, you can also say Hashem's name during zmiros if you have kavanah.

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing some evidence. As it stands now it is merely the assertion of an anonymous internet user whom none of us know.